# Short notation to indicate that a quantity is of order one without using an equals sign?

Tags: notation

Consider a plot in which one axis represents a variable from which a dimensionless number is formed, say a velocity, $u$, and the dimensionless number we are considering is the Reynolds number, $\mathrm{Re}$.  I'd like to indicate the position on the axis for $u$ where $\mathrm{Re} = O(1)$ with say, a vertical line.  Note that $u$ may vary over several orders of magnitude and may be represented on a log scale axis.  I would like to highlight the significance of the line/point on the axis with a label, preferably a single symbol rather than a short expression.  I'm looking for a shorthand for the $\mathrm{Re} = O(1)$ expression.  What would be accepted here?  Can I include a modifier symbol with $\mathrm{Re}$ to indicate that is approximately equal to unity / of order one?  A subsript?  A special font?  Should I let a special (different) symbol be $\mathrm{Re}$ when equal to $O(1)$.  This is a notation question, strictly speaking.

Comment: I think this is kind of an XY problem, because strictly speaking what you are asking makes no sense. Strictly speaking, Re is always O(1) for any fixed values of the dimensional parameters unless some of them become 0 or infinity. Instead I would just label the actual orders of magnitude of Re at a few points in the plot.

Comment: I have modified the question to hopefully make things more clear